# What properties did Disney buy from 21st Century Fox?

Tags: copyright, disney, 20th-century-fox

Disney bought some 21st Century Fox properties, which is quite hyped in the news all around and attracting jokes like these:

[image][image]

Making fun of Xenomorph daughters being Disney princesses now :D

But the serious concern is I am not sure what Disney got out of that deal, what properties do they now possess?

The more I read about it the more I get confused.

What new properties does Disney now own, which previously belonged to Fox? Did they take the rights for there TV and film, i.e. both versions, or was the deal exclusively for only the films or it's TV properties?

Comment: Well, perhaps the "Aliens"-franchise  lacks a princess - but it certainly got a queen!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

According to [this article](https://www.deseretnews.com/article/900005930/here-are-all-the-major-tv-shows-movies-and-channels-disney-is-about-to-acquire-from-fox.html),

### Movies

Disney will acquire following movie franchises from Fox.

- X-Men movies
- Fantastic Four movies
- Star Wars (the rights to the original and prequel trilogies)
- Deadpool series
- Avatar series
- Planet of the Apes series

It will also acquire some of the older films.

- Night at the Museum films
- Home Alone films
- Doctor Dolittle films
- Alvin and the Chipmunks films

**Though, it should be noted** that [Alien franchise is now owned by Disney](https://www.vox.com/culture/2017/12/14/16764472/disney-fox-deal-merger) (Thanks to Kutulmike for correction).

### TV Shows

- “Modern Family” — Airs on ABC, produced by 20th Century Fox Television
- “Speechless” — Airs on ABC, co-produced by Fox and ABC
- “This Is Us” — Airs on NBC, produced by Fox
- “Empire” — Airs on Fox, produced by Fox
- “The X-Files” (revived) — Airs on and produced by Fox
- “The Gifted” — Airs on and produced by Fox
- “The Americans” — Airs on FX, produced by FX Productions
- “It’s Always Sunny in Philadelphia” — Airs on FX, produced by FX Productions
- “The Simpsons” — Produced by Fox Television Animation
- “Family Guy” — Produced by Fox Television Animation
- “Bob’s Burgers” — Produced by Fox Television Animation
- “American Dad!” — Produced by Fox Television Animation
- “King of the Hill” — Produced by Fox Television Animation

Some older TV Shows are-

- “24”
- “Buffy the Vampire Slayer”
- “Hill Street Blues”
- “M_A_S*H”
- “The Mary Tyler Moore Show”
- “The Shield”

### Channels

Disney will acquire more channels from the deal, including:

- 20th Century Fox
- National Geographic
- Fox Networks Group
- FX
- Star
- Endemol Shine Group

### Sports Networks

- YES Network (which covers the New York Yankees)
- Fox Sports Regional networks (often spread throughout the country)
- Sky Sports
- Star Sports
- Fox Deportes

Other references-

1. [New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/12/14/business/media/disney-fox-espn-tv.html)
2. [Polygon](https://www.polygon.com/2017/12/14/16778224/disney-fox-deal-movies-tv-rights)
3. [Axios](https://www.axios.com/heres-what-the-new-disney-fox-merger-looks-like-2517622245.html)
4. [Vox](https://www.vox.com/culture/2017/12/14/16764472/disney-fox-deal-merger)
5. [Business Insider](https://www.businessinsider.in/How-Hollywood-will-fundamentally-change-after-the-Disney-Fox-deal/articleshow/62072483.cms)
6. [Polygon](https://www.polygon.com/2017/12/14/16775978/disney-fox-x-men-avengers-marvel-simpsons)

Comment: does it means that MCU can now use the M word ?

Comment: @dna I am not sure. I couldn't find any information about this yet.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're incorrect about the _Alien_ franchise. Every single article I've read claims that Fox sold _everything_ to Disney except news and sports.

Comment: @KutuluMike What articles I've read don't. Please share those articles. I added articles in the end as well.

Comment: https://www.vox.com/culture/2017/12/14/16764472/disney-fox-deal-merger
https://www.polygon.com/2017/12/14/16775978/disney-fox-x-men-avengers-marvel-simpsons
http://www.businessinsider.com/how-hollywood-changes-disney-fox-merger-2017-12 https://www.axios.com/heres-what-the-new-disney-fox-merger-looks-like-2517622245.html

Comment: @KutuluMike The last article doesn't mention so, but I don't think it matters. :)

Comment: @AJ not all the articles are listing all the properties, but they're all in agreement that Disney bought "Fox's movie studios", which would include the IP for all those movies.

Comment: The Deseret article takes some liberties with some things, specifically the Star Wars 1977 perpetuity rights. It references the NYT article for that, which only says " But Fox has retained the distribution rights to the first film, “Episode IV — A New Hope,” in perpetuity." which would indicate that Disney did **not** buy the rights to Star Wars Episode IV. None of the other articles listed discuss that unique situation, either.

Comment: Can you add quote blocks to the info from the original article?

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know about the unique situation with Ep IV. I noticed a couple of weeks ago that Ep I-VII are on Netflix *except* Ep IV, and I suspected an IP ownership reason. Nice to see that confirmed.

Comment: @ChrisClayton - It goes a bit further than that; there were quite a few *characters* (hero and villain) Marvel was unable to use, due to Fox owning the X-men rights. Probably worth its own question.

Comment: @TED the missing characters are the obvious things. The more subtle things are that some characters which they did have rights to, they weren't able to treat "properly" since they couldn't use certain terms, like mutant. The obvious examples there being Scarlet Witch and Quicksilver.

Comment: Which one of the Avatar 'series' is that? The one by James Cameron with the blue people or the last airbender that M. Night Shyamalan did things to?

Comment: @Valthek James Cameron one.